# Mounting hard drive to an existing folder

Tags: hard-drive, mountpoint

I am attempting to mount an external harddrive at /home which has files in it. Will the files already existing in /home be merged and moved to the new harddrive. If this is not possible are the files lost in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The existing files in `/home` are neither moved nor lost. They remain inaccessible from `/home` until you unmount the driver. Any changes you make in `/home` after mounting are reflected on the contents of the external drive, and the contents of `/home` remain unaffected. It would be better if you chose a subdirectory to mount.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the issue is that this is a shared computer and  the users often need to store huge data which is accessible only to that particular user. So I am trying to mount it under /home. Is there a way to do that?